# Python create sublist from list and number of element

Tags: python, sublist

My existants list:

```
list1 = [0L, 1L, 2L, 7L, 8L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L]

list2 = [5,2,2]
```

The list that I want:

```
OutList = [[0L, 1L, 2L, 7L, 8L], [3L, 4L], [5L, 6L]]
```

How can I do that?

Comment: Show us what you have tried.

Comment: show first what you have tried

Comment: and format your code please. As the person asking the question you have to try more than the one answering it somehow.

Comment: @Jean-François Fabre thanks a lot for show me the duplucate question. The solution is : [list1 [sum(list2 [:i]):sum(list2 [:i+1])] for i in range(len(list2))]

Comment: it's not me. I just edited your post